# Why do I have to delete my build and dist files to successfully upload a new version of a package to Pypi?

Tags: pypi

I get a 400 client error file already exists if all I do is change the version number in setup.py

My program is just a "hello world".

Some friends told me to delete build and dist and then it works but I couldn't find anywhere else on the internet why this is. All the tutorials I came across kind of just hand waved updating or said changing version number with bump version would allow this.

Comment: Not enough information. Show the command(s) you have run. Show the content of directory `dist`. My guess is that you have had old packages in `dist` and `twine` tried to upload them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `twine upload dist/*`. By default, this will tell `twine` to upload everything in the `dist` directory. However, if you're already uploaded some of these distributions, you won't be able to upload them again.

Instead, you can either specify the exact distribution you're trying to upload:

```
twine upload dist/yourproject-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

Or use the `--skip-existing` flag:

```
twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
```